# Thumbnail card with buttons to Telegram channel produces InternalServerError

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Sending thumbnailcard to telegram channel produces following exception. This is working fine in emulator.

Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

Here is the code for card:

```
var Card = new ThumbnailCard(cardHeading, BotName)
{
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    {
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "MyProfile", text:"MyProfile", displayText: "MyProfile", value: "MyProfile"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "MyBadges", text:"MyBadges", displayText: "MyBadges", value: "MyBadges"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "MyActivity", text:"MyActivity", displayText: "MyActivity", value: "MyActivity"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "LogOut", text: "LogOut", displayText: "LogOut", value: "LogOut")
    },
    Images = new List<CardImage>()
    {
        new CardImage()
        {
            Url = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", strBase64Image)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I doubt your `CardImage` `Url` format is correct.  could you please try with `Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg") }`. And Let me know if is it working.

Comment: Yes it did work. So now what is the correct url for embedded image encoded as base64 ?

Comment: When would you use `Url` property inside `CardImage` it expect a link from where it would load that resource.You should better refer a link instead of base64.

Comment: It is working in emulator so I guess the issue is with the channel.

Comment: Yes right you are, Emulator could manage it but all the channel could not for base64.

Comment: I added my comment as answer so that next time someone may get help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt your CardImage Url format is correct. could you please try with  below code snippet

```cs
Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg") }
```

***Point To Remember:***

Emulator could manage many of the issue itself where channel always doesn't.

And Let me know if is it working

Answer (score 3):

From [the attachments sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Bots/AttachmentsBot.cs#L163-L166):

```
// Using a base64 string to send an attachment will not work on all channels.
// Additionally, some channels will only allow certain file types to be sent this way.
// For example a .png file may work but a .pdf file may not on some channels.
// Please consult the channel documentation for specifics.
```

We can surmise from this information that Telegram does not support embedded images.

Comment: Looks good. Telegram seems to be pretty restrictive and WhatsApp is not available. What is the best channel to use from functionality point of view ?

Comment: @AbiSinghal - That really depends on the specific functionality you're looking for. Direct Line is the channel built specifically for the Bot Framework and it gives you the freedom to make your own client or use the prebuilt client Web Chat. Microsoft Teams also integrates very closely with the Bot Framework, and it supports many things like group conversations and message updates. Each channel offers its own documentation that you can look into.